Creating a page test in Sitecore and starting it causes long running publishing job
When we create a new AB page test in Sitecore and start the test, it adds a publishing job that takes a long time to complete. Have any others experienced this, and if so, is there a workaround?

We are on Sitecore XP 10.2 with SXA.

I experienced same issue with Publishing.DeepScanRelatedItems setting which is enabled by default starting from one of the Sitecore 10.x versions.
<setting name="Publishing.DeepScanRelatedItems" value="true" />

Changing the value of the setting to false fixed the issue and solved plenty of other publishing related performance issues.
More about the setting itself:
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/latest/platform-administration-and-architecture/enable-or-disable-publishing-deep-scan.html
Here is a patch file you can use to disable the setting:
<configuration xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <settings role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement">
            <setting name="Publishing.DeepScanRelatedItems">
                <patch:attribute name="value">false</patch:attribute>
            </setting>
        </settings>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>

